# Preloading Images using base64

Tags: php, javascript, animation, base64, preload

I have made a 'drag and drop' file upload utility for my users. I made an upload progress bar out of 13 PMG images and animated it using jQuery. That is working quite well if the user just drops one or two files at the same time. But I noticed that if the user drops 10 files the browser makes a request for every image (130 requests). Sometimes the browser takes these images from cache, but sometimes not. So, my solution was to preload the images like this:

```
function preload()
{ 
    // create object
    imageObj = new Image();

    // set image list
    images = new Array();
    images[0]="img/ProgressBarContent.png";
    images[1]="img/ProgressbarEndEffect.png";
    images[2]="img/0.png";
    images[3]="img/1.png";
    images[4]="img/2.png";
    images[5]="img/3.png";
    images[6]="img/4.png";
    images[7]="img/5.png";
    images[8]="img/6.png";
    images[9]="img/7.png";
    images[10]="img/8.png";
    images[11]="img/9.png";
    images[12]="img/percentIcon.png";
    images[13]="img/ProgressBar.png";

    // start preloading
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) 
    {
        imageObj.src=images[i];

        if(i == (images.length-1))
        {
        //preloading done, give a visual feedback and droping functionality can be activated 
        hideLoadingOverlay();
        }     
     }
 }
```

But that did not made any difference.
So I thought I could let a PHP script read the images I need, encode them as base64 and output them as a JavaScript array like this:

```
$file= base64_encode( file_get_contents ( 'img/0.png') );
echo 'images["img/0.png"] = "data:image/png;base64,'.$file.'";';
```

That way I could also "hardcode" the images directly into my HTML, right?
I thought that in JavaScript I could do this:

```
$(".selector").attr("src", images['filename']);
```

Is this a good solution? Or is there a "proper"/better way?

Thanks!

EDIT:
It does not matter if old browsers do not support this. The scripts are used for a administration area which will only be used by people I know. (And they all have modern browsers.)

Comment: Self Answer:

I am so sorry. I forgot to cal the preload function... :( 
I am really sorry and thank everyone for your help! It's working fine now. 

Nick

Comment: How do you preload a base64 image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` URI scheme isn't supported by IE (or if it is, it's a very recent addition).

I'd fix the fact that the browser isn't always taking the image from the cache, since it should be. Double check you aren't using a variant of the URI for some calls, and then check that the headers sent are appropriate and giving a max-age of at least an hour, if not more.

It also never hurts with images for this sort of use to use pngslim or similar to shave off every byte of what'll be sent.

Comment: IE 9 and later have full support for Data URI's

Answer (score 1):

A better idea may be to make sure that your web server is issuing proper cache headers for your images, once you do that the browsers will only request them once and pull from the cache for subsequent requests. If you not any help with configuring your cache settings feel free to comment on this answer with what web server you use and I'll edit my answer.

Furthermore you can preload all of the images once when the page load using javascript to make sure that the browser has them cached by the time they need to be displayed like this:

```
var imageObj = new Image();
var images = new Array();
images[0]="image1.jpg"
images[1]="image2.jpg"
images[2]="image3.jpg"
images[3]="image4.jpg"

for(var i=0; i < images.length; i++) {
    imageObj.src=images[i];
}
```

**Edit, setting up caching in apache2**

You can configure these settings on a per-directory/per-file basis using a .htaccess file, which you can read more about [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/htaccess.html). Basically, what you want to do is create a .htaccess file in your document root, and put in something like this:

```
# cache images for 10 days
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
  Header unset Pragma
  FileETag None
  Header unset ETag
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=864000, public, must-revalidate"
  Header unset Last-Modified
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I am using Xampp for MacOs for development (so i guess Apache) and my hoster uses Apache as well and PHP Version 5.4.5. So please help me with configuring my cache settings. Thank you very much again! =)

Comment: Thanks! That is really interesting. But the problem was that i forgot to call my preload function. (headbang)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is create a sprite so if the image is 10x10 and you have 10 frames in your animation, you will create a sprite that is 10x100.

Then you make a classes, each offsetting the background 10 pixels.  Instead of loading a separate image for each frame, the same image is offset to create the animation.

the css in our situation would look like this:

```
.sprite {
    background: url('/images/sprite.png');
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
.sprite.frame1 {
    background-position: 0 -10px;
}
.sprite.frame2 {
    background-position: 0 -20px;
}
...
```

the js could look something like this:

```
for (i=0;i!=11;i++) {
    document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "sprite frame" + i;
}
```

You get the picture.  The image will only be loaded once, even if you have 100 animations on the screen.